# How to render value from database as HTML

Tags: polymer, lit-html

Is it possible to reneder value from any external source (database, files, etc.) like 'some text' on page as pure HTML with using LIT-HTML? I'm trying to do it by assinging this value to variable like that:

```
var variable = html `{$database.value}`
```

but it doesn't work. I still see text on the page instead of HTML tags (div, a)

Comment: `$database` seems php, is it server-side or client-side code? Or you meant ``html`${database.value}` ``?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `unsafeHTML` directive for this: https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/template-reference#unsafehtml